# Git checkout doesn't get latest changes

Tags: git, version-control

I've made a number of commits to a Git branch, synched them to the repository, and then checked out a fresh copy of the branch onto another computer using:

```
git checkout
```

however the latest change that I'm seeing on the 2nd computer is a few steps behind the version on the 1st computer. I've tried a:

```
git reset --hard head
```

on the branch, on the 2nd computer. What is happening?

Comment: Have you run `git fetch origin` before `git checkout`?

Comment: Thanks, that worked :)

Comment: Should I make this an answer? )

Comment: Yes, please. I've researched 'fetch' and 'checkout' however I don't see why fetch would work when I'd made a fresh checkout. Could you also explain why this would make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git repository usually has its own version of remote refs, updated each time you do `git fetch <remote-name>` (on its own or as part of `git pull <remote-name> <branch-name>` operation). The point is, `git checkout` uses this information *without* checking the corresponding remote. In other words, if someone updates the branch on remote, you won't be able to get those updates with `git checkout` - you'll have to pull the necessary information from remote first.

Answer (score -1):

try

`git checkout <your_branch>`